# Bixby: this weekend, next weekend is returning the same value

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Today i am testing my app and trying to modify the static message i am providing to user. So

On 2019-05-07 
1: When i say, next weekend, it returned start day 2019-05-10 and end day 2019-05-12 and also giving me extra information like offset: Next and namedTimeIntervalRel: Weekend. But I hit the next weekend query again so the extra information won't appear and the date was same. I need extra information so that i could message user that this result is for next weekend.

2: When i say this weekend, It returned the same date and extra information as well and no matter how many time I hit the this weekend query, every time I get the extra information.

So, How would i get the extra information every time and why next weekend is this weekend?

If extra information is not possible, is there any way i can calculate and find whether user asked for this weekend or next or next month and so on?

Comment: Heads up that officially, the assistant is known as "Bixby", not "BixBy".

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce the issue (not seeing the `offset` and `namedTimeIntervalRel`) as you have described it. 
This could potentially be a bug. 
I'd suggest that you raise it with Bixby Developer Support through Bixby Studio Help -> Contact Support so you can track it and be notified when it is fixed.

As regards to `this weekend` and `next weekend`, Bixby's convention appears to similar to this interpretation: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29104/this-weekend-vs-next-weekend

Comment: Alright... But for now even if I calculate the difference between today and the weekend, so based on calculation how would I describe whether it is this weekend or next weekend. e.g: user asked about next weekend and I will get the date of 3 days later and as per the calculation 3 days would be this weekend but user has asked about next weekend. So if I will message user that we found result for this weekend, but user has asked about next weekend. Sorry for long explanation but I hope you understand

Comment: To remove any ambiguity, maybe, you can present the two weekend dates to the user and ask them to select one of them

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround for strange selection when repeating utterance with "this weekend" or "tonight"

add default-select

```
    input (dateTimeExpression) {
      type (MyDateTimeExpression)
        min (Optional)
      default-select {
        with-rule: select-first
      }
    }
```

Adding this may require some other changes as now it will select first dateTimeExpression when there is more than one.

And for the "this weekend" vs "next weekend" issue, I would suggest using conversation drives as a continuation of search result. You can construct "How about next day/week/weekend" as conversation driver depend on the input (this would not be easy, but definitely possible).

So, when user ask about **next weekend** Bixby will display **this weekend** result, but user can easily check **next weekend** result by click conversation drives or say "next weekend"

Hope this would help.
Have fun with Bixby!

Comment: As per the first suggestions I have raised issue with the support team and I hope they are looking into it, but for now have handle the situation in my code. But I would love to have those extra variables in it.