# Bixby: Unable to print message

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

user: set my location to new york
Bixby will asked for permission and then asked to store the location and then asked to choose from list of map. User will click one and i will message user that your location is set to New York, USA. Everthing is good. But When i click on the map to select address, I won't get the message but if I voice command like "First one" or type "first one", then i get the message.

My location is result view where in message I checked if levelOne.subdivisionCode exists and country name exists, it will combine and message.

I have summary `layout-macro` and details 'layout-macro'.

Please let me know if you need some more information. and let me know why my message is not appearing when click select the map?

result view:

```
result-view {
  match: Location (this)
  message{
     if (exists(this.levelOne.subdivisionCode) && exists(this.country.name)){
       template ("Your location is set to #{value(this.name)}, #{value(this.country.name)}. You can now browse by saying following statement.")
     }else-if (exists(this.country.name)){
       template ("Your location is set to #{value(this.country.name)}. You can now browse by saying following statement.")
     }else{
       template ("We are unable to find any city")
     }
}
```

Summary-layout

```
where-each (album) {
   layout-macro (location-summary) {
      param (location) {              
        expression (album)
    }
  }
}
```

Detail Layout

```
layout-macro (location-details) {
  param(location) {
    expression (this)
  }
}
```

Comment: It might help to see the result view as well as the layout macros for summary and details to get a full picture of how the visual representation is defined. Can you add those to your description?

Comment: Thanks... Would love to have update on this one

Comment: Need some time to check on this. Updated the other question's answer in the appropriate page.

Comment: @RahulGupta I believe SDK 19J release added this feature. I also updated the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue that we'll need to investigate further. Can you submit a bug report via Bixby Studio?

Comment: Have already raised issue for another issue and my capsule is for the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56023687/5242097.   Have already raised this question and also shared diagnostic report

Answer (score 0):

With new SDK 19J release, this issue is solved by enable **allow-dialogs-on-detail-pages** in runtime-flags

---

After talking with internal team, it is a generic issue we became aware of.

Current version of Bixby does NOT render message section when click from a list of results. The UL utterance "first one" actually re-run the search and display a single result, thus the message is rendered.

A request to add feature of displaying dialog/message when click a list of results is submitted to product management team. Please continue your capsule development with Bixby, and we'll see if next release include such feature.

Have fun with Bixby! And thank you for sharing the diagnostic report with us!